# Como muestro un vector en un QlistWidget

Tags: c++, qt

```
Contactos::Contactos(vector<Contact> a,QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Contactos)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listWidgetContactos->addItem(&a[0]);
}
```

> **error**: no matching member function for call to 'addItem'
>   C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtWidgets\qlistwidget.h:217: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type *' (aka 'Contact *') to 'const QString' for 1st argument
>   C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_64\include\QtWidgets\qlistwidget.h:328: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type *' (aka 'Contact *') to 'QListWidgetItem *' for 1st argument

Mi clase `Contact` es así:

```
class Contact {
  QString nombreContacto;

public:
  QString getNombreContacto( ) const;
  void setNombreContacto( const QString &value );
};
```

Comment: Si deseas ayuda debes mostrar el mensaje de error completo

Comment: liswidegetContactos es un listWidget solo le agregue el nombre contactos para identificarlo, el error esta en que no se como mostrar el vector. Se que si lo escribo como ui->listWidgetContactos->additem(""), pero si pomgo el vector directamente me aparece ese error

Comment: `class Contact
{
private:
    QString nombreContacto;
public:
    Contact();
    QString getNombreContacto() const;
    void setNombreContacto(const QString &value);

};`

Comment: QListWidget solo acepta QListWidgetItem, no acepta a Contact. Asi que un solucion es usar el QString de Contact para crear un QListWidgetItem, para ello cambia `ui->listWidgetContactos->addItem(&a[0]);` a `ui->listWidgetContactos->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(a[0].getNombreContacto()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ui->listWidgetContactos->addItem(&a[0]);
```

Con la línea anterior, le estás pasando al `QListWidget` un puntero de tipo `Contact` y el problema es precisamente que `QListWidget` no sabe qué hacer con un objeto de ese tipo.

Si miramos la interfaz de [`QListWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html) vemos que nos ofrece 2 posibilidades para `addItem`:

```
void    addItem(const QString & label)
void    addItem(QListWidgetItem * item)
```

La primera es simple, le pasamos el texto a mostrar y el widget se encarga de lo demás.

La segunda, en cambio, requiere que le pasemos un objeto de tipo `QListWidgetItem`. Este objeto es más potente que un simple *string*, pero también requiere más código.

Si simplemente te interesa rellenar la lista con el primer método te sobra. Únicamente tienes que pensar qué debe contener el texto que le pasas como parámetro. Por ejemplo:

```
QString texto = a[0].getNombreContacto();
ui->listWidgetContactos->addItem(texto);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!